# Text is not responsive on poster image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, responsive

I have issues with my text over my images. The text I have is working when it's in desktop, at least on my computer resolution. But the issue is when I scale it back it doesn't keep up with the images so to say. Any idea how to do so or what is wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-4 text-center image-capsule mx-auto">
  <section class="posters-section">
    <a href="/" class="movie-link pop">
      <p class="poster-date">Test</p>
      <img class="img-fluid poster" data-toggle="popover" src="${app.movie[0].poster}">
    </a>
  </section>
  <h5 class="mt-3">${app.movie[0].title}</h5>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-capsule {
  width: 33%;
  position: relative;
}

.posters-section {
  position: relative;
}

.poster {
  position: relative;
}

.poster-date {
  margin: -5% 26%;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #9c0000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 51%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this. I fixed this issue by using bootstraps text-center class on the text. This kept them centered in the div holding the picture which kept them together with a picture. Here is an example of what I did.

```
<div class="margin-intercept shrink-to-necessary-size">    
                        <a href="350_project.html">
                            <img src="images/IMG_2579.JPG" width="350" height="350">
                        </a>

                        <h3 class="picwidth text-center">350 Project</h3>

                    </div>
```

This made the text stay centered under the image no matter how the screen shrunk.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your example, I cannot get it to work even if I add text-center on my code.